# How does signum extend to non-numeric sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Many elementary operations that are taught in grade school have nice extensions to abstract algebra. Addition and multiplication form the foundation of field theory. The exponential function extends into an exponential field; the absolute value function expands nicely into the concept of a norm on a vector space.

However, one operation still eludes me. Seen frequently in the computing field, the $signum$ operator is defined on the reals as follows.
$$
signum(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1, x < 0 \\
\phantom- 0, x = 0 \\
\phantom- 1, x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
Is there a useful way to extend this into an algebraic structure, specifically while maintaining the property that $x = | x | \cdot signum(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain? It seems like this should be something close to a normed vector space (since the property would be maintained in $\mathbb{R}^n$ fairly easily by defining $signum(x) = \frac{x}{||x||}$).

Comment: I like this question. I also think you answered it yourself, in a sense; $\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}$ is sort of a way to turn a vector $x$ into a pure "direction", by dividing out its length. Your observation is that $signum(x)$ does the same thing for numbers, and only records whether they point left, right, or nowhere at all :)

Comment: @pjs36 That is definitely true. It hadn't even occurred to me that $\frac{x}{||x||}$ extends so nicely to vector spaces anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably, you could define a $\operatorname{sign}$ function on any ordered abelian group $G$; you have a $0$ element and an ordering, so it makes sense to write
$$\operatorname{signum}(g)=\begin{cases}
\hphantom{\mathrel{-}}1 & \text{ if }g>0\\
\hphantom{\mathrel{-}}0 & \text{ if }g=0\\
-1 & \text{ if }g<0
\end{cases}\qquad \qquad \operatorname{abs}(g)=\begin{cases}
\hphantom{\mathrel{-}}g & \text{ if }g\geq 0\\
-g & \text{ if }g <0
\end{cases}$$
and in an abelian group it makes sense to multiply by integers, so it's true that $$g=\operatorname{signum}(g)\cdot\operatorname{abs}(g).$$